# Alternative for huge if else statement

Tags: c#, asp.net, if-statement

I have a huge data, and I need to filter them to get certain value according to Choices, I tried to use if else but it was so hard because it is really huge and nested.

```
if(Type == "H" && Tech =="2A")
{
    if(Level == "ground")
    {
        return "2AA";
    }
    else if (Level == "UP")
    {
        return "2AB";
    }
}
else if(Type == "H" && Tech =="3A")
{
    if(Level == "ground")
    {
        return "3AA";
    }
    else if (Level == "UP")
    {
        return "3AB";
    }

}
else if(Type == "E" && Tech =="2B")
    {
        if(Level == "ground")
        {
            return "3BB";
        }
        else if (Level == "UP")
        {
            return "3BC";
        }
    }
```

And so on in each if.

**Edit

Type & Level & tech is a strings comes from other method.
this code is a brief, the real code contains like 30 if else inside each if.

Comment: Is there any logic in the values? Can you use that to make just two `if` statements and append the results?

Comment: can you put some more details? can you add example data and how you are processing it?

Comment: more like https://codereview.stackexchange.com/ related

Comment: Would be better if you explained the scenario you're trying to implement.

Comment: Each choice returns the name of table to use later in SELECT statement .

Comment: @ilkerkaran I would close the current question on Code Review. Lacking context around the code, and lacking a general description.

Comment: I would not describe this as **huge**.

Comment: it is like a 30 if and else in side each if , i write a brief , and type is just a string comes from another method, like level and other string values.

Comment: Why not store these in a class (list) then for each it? Makes it more maintainable in case you need to add more.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because its a review and thus should go to codereview.stackexchange.com

Comment: You can create a dictionary of string key and string value. Populate the dictionary by joining various combinations of Type, Tech and Level string and value for those combinations. And return the value by doing `dict[Type+Tech+Level]`

Comment: @HimBromBeere No. Read my earlier comment.

Comment: use a database  ,set all your data and actions in table and just query the result ,like "SELECT result 
FROM `mydata`  
WHERE `Type ` = TypeValue 
    AND `Tech ` = TechValue
    AND `Level ` = Level "
    AND `Level ` = Level "

Comment: So basically each unique combination of Type, Tech and Level produced a different results - which means you can use mapping

Answer (score 2):

From what you have provided, I can **assume** you can do this:

Create a dictionary for levels and a string array for types:

```
Dictionary<string, string> levels = new Dictionary<string, string>
{
    { "ground", "A" },
    { "UP", "B" },
};

string[] types = { "H", "E" };
```

then let's assume you have this inputs:

```
string tech = "2A";
string level = "ground";
string type = "H";
```

so you can now do this:

```
if (types.Contains(type))
{
    string result = $"{tech}{levels[level]}";
}
```

Comment: Unless he made a mistake, Type E Tech 2B Ground returns 3BB.

Comment: Thanks, you helped me a lot i can use something like that .

Comment: If such a solution works for you, @Fatmaelzahraa, then you may want to consider using a HashSet<string> instead of string[] if (and only if) you're going to have a lot of values.

Answer (score 0):

You can use [C# 8.0's new feature](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/whats-new/csharp-8) called Tuple patterns.

```
public static string Choice(string type, string tech, string level)
    => (type, tech, level) switch
    {
        ("H", "2A", "ground") => "2AA",
        ("H", "2A", "UP") => "2AB",
        ("H", "3A", "ground") => "3AA",
        ("H", "3A", "UP") => "3AB",
        ("E", "2B", "ground") => "3BB",
        ("E", "2B", "UP") => "3BC",
        (_, _, _) => null
    };
```

and use simply as:

```
return Choice(Type, Tech, Level);
```

Comment: the problem is i have like 30 kind of level and the same with Tech and Types.

Comment: Then you need to explain your logic a bit more.

Comment: I've completely changed my answer now. Hope this helps you.